# Find radius x, the answer is not 2, image is in the link below.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, triangles

[image]

Help me to find radius $x$, the answer is not 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using Pythagoras twice we obtain  the following equation.
$$\sqrt{(12+x)^2-x^2}=12+\sqrt{(4-x)^2-x^2}.$$
I got $$x=\frac{3\sqrt{21}-7}{4}.$$

Here is illustration of how we get equation

[image]

Comment: You can add that you use pythagoras theorem twice. Thank

Comment: I added it. Thank you!